# Pass an object reference into a Data structure

Tags: c#

How could I possibly do the following:

```
OrderedDictionary<string, object> bag = new OrderedDictionary<string, object>();

public void Add(string str,ref object obj) {
    bag.Add(str,**ref obj**);
}
```

So anytime I'll want to access that specific 'obj' inside 'bag', it will refer to the passed 'obj' in the arguments.

Comment: `objects` are reference types. So if you access the obj in the dictionary, you access this very object. The `ref` modifier is a kind of symbolic link to a variable. But this variable may not exist anymore, if you read the dictionary values. So what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Thank you, got the problem, I might need to declare the passed object outside of the method so it won't be cleaned.

Comment: `"so it wont be cleaned"`? if you have your object in an ordered dictionary, the garbage collector wont collect it - if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects are already reference types. Accessing the object in your dictionary will modify the original obj.

What you have is multiple references to the same object in memory. So modifying or copying or anything like that will work correctly and persist in the same object. Keep in mind though, that if you want to **set** the object to something else (like null) it will only be setting the current reference to null, and not the actual object.

ref on the other hand, is useful for passing the actual **reference** as a parameter, and not the object in memory. Take this for example:

```
void SomeMethod(object obj)
{
    obj = null;
}

void SomeRefMethod(ref object obj)
{
    obj = null;
}
```

With this invocation:

```
object obj1 = new object();

Console.WriteLine(obj1 == null); //False

SomeMethod(obj1);
Console.WriteLine(obj1 == null); //False

SomeMethodRef(ref obj1);
Console.WriteLine(obj1 == null); //True
```

In this situation, `obj1` will still be `non-null` after the call to `SomeMethod`, and it will be `null` after the call to `SomeMethodRef`.